# Set android camera preview fit half the screen

Tags: android, android-camera, zxing

I need to implement barcode scanning app. The specific feature is that I need the preview displays in fragment which fits half a screen (or say 250 dp). So, I use [this](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner) library and its [ScannerFragment](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner/blob/master/zxing/sample/src/main/java/me/dm7/barcodescanner/zxing/sample/ScannerFragment.java) class to implement camera preview and barcode scanning.
The issue is that in portrait (I need only this mode, not landscape) mode camera preview is stretched and scanner cant recognize barcode in it. It landscape mode works fine.

My layout file:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top">

        <fragment android:name="ua.xajker.inventarization.BarcodeScanActivity.ScannerFragment"
            android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My Fragment class:

```
public class ScannerFragment extends Fragment implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
    private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(getActivity());
        return mScannerView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);

        mScannerView.startCamera();
        mScannerView.setAutoFocus(false);
    }


    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Contents = " + rawResult.getText() +
                ", Format = " + rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mScannerView.startCamera();
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mScannerView.stopCamera();
    }
}
```

I found that we can replace lib's ZXingScannerView.java class where we can manipulate with Camera object, maybe it would help in some way?

```
public class ZXingScannerView extends BarcodeScannerView {

    public interface ResultHandler {
        public void handleResult(Result rawResult);
    }


    private MultiFormatReader mMultiFormatReader;
    public static final List<BarcodeFormat> ALL_FORMATS = new ArrayList<BarcodeFormat>();
    private List<BarcodeFormat> mFormats;
    private ResultHandler mResultHandler;


    static {
        ALL_FORMATS.add(BarcodeFormat.UPC_A);
        ALL_FORMATS.add(BarcodeFormat.UPC_E);
        ALL_FORMATS.add(BarcodeFormat.EAN_13);
        ALL_FORMATS.add(BarcodeFormat.EAN_8);
        ALL_FORMATS.add(BarcodeFormat.RSS_14);
        ALL_FORMATS.add(BarcodeFormat.CODE_39);
        ALL_FORMATS.add(BarcodeFormat.CODE_93);
        ALL_FORMATS.add(BarcodeFormat.CODE_128);
        ALL_FORMATS.add(BarcodeFormat.ITF);
        ALL_FORMATS.add(BarcodeFormat.CODABAR);
        ALL_FORMATS.add(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
        ALL_FORMATS.add(BarcodeFormat.DATA_MATRIX);
        ALL_FORMATS.add(BarcodeFormat.PDF_417);
    }


    public ZXingScannerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initMultiFormatReader();
    }


    public ZXingScannerView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
        initMultiFormatReader();
    }


    public void setFormats(List<BarcodeFormat> formats) {
        mFormats = formats;
        initMultiFormatReader();
    }


    public void setResultHandler(ResultHandler resultHandler) {
        mResultHandler = resultHandler;
    }


    public Collection<BarcodeFormat> getFormats() {
        if(mFormats == null) {
            return ALL_FORMATS;
        }
        return mFormats;
    }


    private void initMultiFormatReader() {
        Map<DecodeHintType,Object> hints = new EnumMap<DecodeHintType,Object>(DecodeHintType.class);
        hints.put(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS, getFormats());
        mMultiFormatReader = new MultiFormatReader();
        mMultiFormatReader.setHints(hints);
    }


    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        Camera.Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();

        int width = size.width;
        int height = size.height;

        if(DisplayUtils.getScreenOrientation(getContext()) == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            byte[] rotatedData = new byte[data.length];
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                    rotatedData[x * height + height - y - 1] = data[x + y * width];
            }
            int tmp = width;
            width = height;
            height = tmp;
            data = rotatedData;
        }


        Result rawResult = null;
        PlanarYUVLuminanceSource source = buildLuminanceSource(data, width, height);


        if(source != null) {
            BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
            try {
                rawResult = mMultiFormatReader.decodeWithState(bitmap);
            } catch (ReaderException re) {
                // continue
            } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                // This is terrible
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aoe) {


            } finally {
                mMultiFormatReader.reset();
            }
        }


        if (rawResult != null) {
            stopCamera();
            if(mResultHandler != null) {
                mResultHandler.handleResult(rawResult);
            }
        } else {
            camera.setOneShotPreviewCallback(this);
        }
    }


    public PlanarYUVLuminanceSource buildLuminanceSource(byte[] data, int width, int height) {
        Rect rect = getFramingRectInPreview(width, height);
        if (rect == null) {
            return null;
        }
        // Go ahead and assume it's YUV rather than die.
        PlanarYUVLuminanceSource source = null;


        try {
            source = new PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(data, width, height, rect.left, rect.top,
                    rect.width(), rect.height(), false);
        } catch(Exception e) {
        }


        return source;
    }
}
```

I haven't reputation to post photos, so you can see screenshot *[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hsd62.png)*.

Thanks a lot for any suggestion.

Comment: 1. If you describe your fragment's location by typing layout_witdth, you should set your layout_width = 0 - thus, you don't request the OS to calculate the width as you don't rely on this parameter.

For more info see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370408/why-androidlayout-width-0px-for-fragments

Comment: 2. What is the point of wrapping the fragment with external FrameLayout? I would either declare FrameLayout and fill it with the fragment instance programmatically or just the fragment itself. 

Here are the Mark Murphy's examples of ZXing usage: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/ZXing 
https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/ZXing-II

Hope this helps somehow.

Comment: I seriously doubt that visual distortion (even though it's very unpleasant and not acceptable as a final result) will cause the barcode scanner to miss the code. But if it expects the barcode to arrive horizontally, it definitely will fail, because in Portrait mode the pictures that arrive to the analyzer are "rotated".